# After double-clicking a script on the desktop, show output in a terminal

Tags: 10.04, command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying to make a demo Virtual Machine. On the desktop, I have a script `foo.sh` and it outputs stdout to `foo.log` (e.g. with `some command > foo.log`)

When I double click on the script, it generates the foo.log. However, I would like for the script to also present the stdout in real time (e.g. using `tail -f foo.log`).

How can I do this? Do I need to pipe the output to two places?

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the most elegant approach, but it appears to work:

Add the following to the script:

```
touch foo.log
uxterm -e "tail -f foo.log" &
some command > foo.log
```

with gnome-terminal, replace `uxterm -e` with `gnome-terminal -x`.

Thanks to the [Hilltop Yodeler](http://www.hilltopyodeler.com/blog/?p=382) for directing me to this solution.

Comment: I was posting that sort of information. Use gnome-terminal -e to call your script, within your script use tee, but tail works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Unix's standard `tee` command allows you to redirect the command's standard input to one or more files and also print it to the standard output. So you can do something like

```
myscript.sh|tee mylog.log
```

provided that myscript.sh just prints to standard output (which would actually simplify it)

To open a terminal windows when you click on icon, you can wrap it in another script:

```
xterm -e "myscript.sh | tee mylog.log; read -p FINISHED"
```

The difference with your solution is that you have a choice to either close the terminal window when the script finished or display "Press any key to continue..." message - with `tail -f` the terminal basically has no way of knowing when your script finished so you have to interrupt it with Ctrl-C.

Also, tail -f must be less efficient that printing directly to terminal, but this is probably not very important these days.

Comment: nope, that does not work; it neither writes a log file nor opens the terminal. Note that I am not executing the script from the terminal, I am executing it by clicking on the desktop icon that represents the script.

Comment: The original solution was answering your question "how to pipe the output in two places" - to open the script in a terminal window you use xterm -e or any other terminal program. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I did Sergy's suggestion and if it worked, it may be a path problem.  Here is the exact command I used and the result was an xterm opening, showing the output of the script and then says "Press return to close ".  I suggest you add path in front of the script name, and possibly the log file name.

```
xterm -e "./myscript.sh | tee ./mylog.log; read -p Press\ return\ to\ close\ "
```

All my version of `myscript.sh` did was to echo several lines, but it worked.